# Quarkus getting-started application throws exception workerPoolSize must be > 0

Tags: quarkus

I was following the steps written here: 
https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#bootstrapping-the-project

Github link:
https://github.com/sujoydc/quarkus-getting-started

System Details:

Apache Maven 3.6.3

Java version: 1.8.0

OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Local compilation result:

```
└─[ ✓ ] ॐ  mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.acme:getting-started >----------------------
[INFO] Building getting-started 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.399 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-13T22:14:23-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>getting-started</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.2.0.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.2.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

After the following statement, I get this exception "Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: workerPoolSize must be > 0". 
I just followed the steps and I don't know where do we set this param "workerPoolSize".

The full stack trace below:

```
  ./mvnw compile quarkus:dev

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.acme:getting-started >----------------------
[INFO] Building getting-started 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.2.0.Final:dev (default-cli) @ getting-started ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
06:38:08,033 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Final
06:38:08,235 ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor#setupProviders threw an exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.set(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1185)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MediaTypeMap.add(MediaTypeMap.java:312)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor.categorizeProviders(ResteasyCommonProcessor.java:218)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor.setupProviders(ResteasyCommonProcessor.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:915)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:279)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext$$Lambda$112/468968371.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1426)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)

    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:181)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.doStart(DevModeMain.java:178)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:96)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:67)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor#setupProviders threw an exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.set(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1185)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MediaTypeMap.add(MediaTypeMap.java:312)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor.categorizeProviders(ResteasyCommonProcessor.java:218)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor.setupProviders(ResteasyCommonProcessor.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:915)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:279)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext$$Lambda$112/468968371.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1426)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:108)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:128)
    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:114)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.set(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1185)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MediaTypeMap.add(MediaTypeMap.java:312)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor.categorizeProviders(ResteasyCommonProcessor.java:218)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor.setupProviders(ResteasyCommonProcessor.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:915)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:279)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext$$Lambda$112/468968371.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1426)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)

06:38:08,238 INFO  [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Attempting to start hot replacement endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
06:38:08,247 ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: workerPoolSize must be > 0
    at io.vertx.core.VertxOptions.setWorkerPoolSize(VertxOptions.java:275)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder.convertToVertxOptions(VertxCoreRecorder.java:152)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder.initializeWeb(VertxCoreRecorder.java:105)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.startServerAfterFailedStart(VertxHttpRecorder.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.deployment.devmode.VertxHotReplacementSetup.handleFailedInitialStart(VertxHotReplacementSetup.java:30)
    at io.quarkus.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.startupFailed(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:452)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.doStart(DevModeMain.java:192)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:96)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:67)
```

Comment: If you can share your project on GitHub, I can trace this error.

Comment: Can you show what your `application.properties` file looks like?

Comment: I ran Step#4 maven command to create this "getting-started" project and the Step#5 throws this error. I didn't do any coding so far. Just trying to make it work as par the steps mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#bootstrapping-the-project

Comment: I tried to reproduce it just now but I can't. Are you on Windows, macOS, Linux? Could you post what your `pom.xml` looks like? It really looks like some version mismatch but executing the commands from the guide works for me.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet I have edited my question with the details you wanted. Please have a look and thanks for your help.

Comment: @geoand,  The default project doesn't have anything in the application.properties, just couple of comments.

Comment: @iabughosh Added the project to github https://github.com/sujoydc/quarkus-getting-started

Comment: ATM, your repo doesn't build at all

Comment: That's the issue, I had followed the steps. So, where did I go wrong? Are there any issues with the steps? Or I am doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @geoand locally it's getting compiled. I have updated the question with compilation result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked your code, you are having compilation error in your resources class, please replace your hello method with the below:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response hello() {
    return Response.ok().entity("hello").build();
}
```

Default code generated by Quarkus was like this :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello() {
    return "hello";
}
```

It worked with java version "openjdk-11.0.2.jdk" and NOT with version "jdk1.8.0.jdk".

Comment: Thanks @iabughosh. I tried that. In the originally generated code, it was returning String. I tried with Response but the committed code was not having the return statement. The problem is not with compilation, the problem is running the code.

Comment: I have updated my github, could you please try again and see.

Comment: That's weird! I run it on my machine it is working fine, also tested this command : curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/hello and I got hello result. We've same environment except for java version. I am using java 11. Can you give it a try with JDK 11 ?

Comment: ya it's really weird. I shall try with JDK 11. Thanks a lot @iabughosh

Comment: Great news @Sujoy ! Please mark this question as answered or with up vote so people having the same issue can find the answer easier.